# ASP.Net MVC form post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc registratrion form

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home" , FormMethod.Post))
                       { %>     
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="username">User Name:</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBox("username") %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("username") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBox("firstName") %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("firstName") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBox("lastName") %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("lastName") %>

                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBox("email") %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("email") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <%= Html.Password("password") %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("password") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm password:</label>
                    <%= Html.Password("confirmPassword") %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("confirmPassword") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="Role">Role:</label>
                    <%= Html.DropDownList("Role",((SelectList)ViewData["Roles"]),"--Select One---") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

// My Homecontroller.cs method

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Register(string username, string firstName, string lastName, string password, string confirmPassword, string email,string role)
        {
            try
            {

                int id =  _usrService.GetRoleId(role);
                Data.User usr = new User(username, firstName, lastName, email, DateTime.Now, null, id);

                if (_usrService.RegisterUser(usr, password, confirmPassword, "none", "none"))
                {
                    return View("Logon");
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Register");
            }


        }
```

on hitting the register button it does not do hit any of the break point in my register method.

Comment: What does it do instead?  Does it perform the redirect?

Comment: @john - yeah it does not hit any of the lines my code , but redirects to logon page

Comment: @Pinu: can you hit *any* breakpoint?

Comment: @John - No I cant hit any break point. I doubt if it is hitting that function

Comment: @Pinu:  I meant even *outside* of that function.  I think that your debugger might be misconfigured.

Comment: @Pinu, there seems to be no issue with the code.. like @John said it might be somthng related to your system

Comment: But it is not even doing what it is suppose to do

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to track the flow?

Comment: If it's redirecting to login page, then you probably need to allow anonymous access to that location in your web.config. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the page is redirecting to the log in page, then the most likely cause is that forms authentication does not allow anonymous access to the target file or directory.  This is configured in the `authorization` and `authentication` elements of your `web.config` file.

These are some links that provide overviews of authentication and authorization in ASP.NET:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140238/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031204-1.aspx#postadlink

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649264.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should remove any `[Authorize]` attribute you might have placed on the `Register` action or the controller containing it. From your description it looks like that authentication is required to invoke the action (because of the `[Authorize]` attribute) and if the user is not authenticated it will simply be redirected to the logon action without ever executing any code in the `Register` action.